# Why it takes Longer to make smaller array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, performance, performance-testing

this is function to make an array from `1 to n`:

```
 function MakeList(n){
       return Array.from(Array(n).keys()).map(function(x){return x+1;});
    }
```

I timed it so I can find the fastest way to make this array:

```
console.log(n);
console.time("MakeList");
var ar = MakeList(n);
console.timeEnd("MakeList");
```

But the output is so weired!:

```
1
MakeList: 0.897ms
2
MakeList: 0.135ms
5
MakeList: 0.048ms
```

why it takes about 20 times longer to make array with length of 1 than 5?

any suggestion for fastest way would be appreciated!

Comment: You're probably warming up your JIT or something. Try doing it in random order, and using lots of iterations. Using just 1 iteration will be almost entirely dominated by noise.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `.map()`.  You could just do this:  `let d = Array.from(Array(n + 1).keys());
d.shift(); return d;`

Comment: FYI, a simple `for` loop initializer seems to be 40x faster in Chrome: https://jsperf.com/create-array-sequence/1 for `n = 5`.

Comment: And, when you do proper performance tests with many iterations in the timing loop for your exact function, they do finish in the expected order: https://jsperf.com/makelist/1 in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Timing one short function call all by itself is so short that very small variations in what else is going on in the interpreter (starting up the JIT, compiling or optimizing some code, allocating some memory) could create variations that would influence the timings you record.  To work around that, most performance tests run thousands of iterations and time the entire block of iterations to make small variations in one iteration insignificant.  For example, if your function with values of 1, 2, 5 and 10 in jsperf which does thousands of iterations for each, then you get the expected finish order in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.  Here are the numbers for Chrome (higher numbers are faster):

```
 makeList(1)    2,470,356 ops/sec
 makeList(2)    1,861,029 ops/sec
 makeList(5)      992,583 ops/sec
 makeList(10)     626,572 ops/sec
```

You can run this yourself in your favorite browser here in [this jsperf](https://jsperf.com/makelist/1).

---

Since you are interested in speed, you could make one immediate improvement and eliminate the `.map()` by changing this:

```
return Array.from(Array(n).keys()).map(function(x){return x+1;});
```

to this:

```
let d = Array.from(Array(n + 1).keys()); 
d.shift(); 
return d;
```

This creates one extra array entry on the original array, then removes the zeroth entry in order to get a 1-based array, rather than recreating a whole new array like you were doing.

---

And, a plain `for` loop initializer appears to be 40x faster in Chrome as shown in [this jsperf](https://jsperf.com/create-array-sequence/1):

```
function makeList2(n) {
    let d = new Array(n);
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        d[i-1] = i;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: @veto - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.